# How to Store session data to a php file

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have website which gives points when they click on name will be redirected  to the linked webpage.These names are stored in my MySQL database. I have used following point system to give point (only 1 point)

```html
<a href="" id="stack-overflow">www.stackoverflow.com</a>
Now in your js file:
$('#stack-overflow').on('click', function() {
count = 1 
  //send a ajax
$.ajax({
  url:'usersdb.php',
  type:'GET'
  dataType: 'json'
  data: {
   points: count,
      },
  success: function(resp){
  $('#stack-overflow').href='www.stackoverflow.com';
  //now triggered this link
  $('#stack-overflow').click();
  //or what ever msg you want to display
  });
  });
```

instead of www.stackoverflow.com  i want to display name form mysql database and link it to `url` in the same column

I have 2 field in MySQL database 1) `url` 2) `name` i want to display randomly name and link it to `url` and display it on database only once and give one point.My signup information are kept in userdb.php. I want to store this point and display it again

Comment: so whats the question? which part are you stuck on? which part of your code isn't working etc etc

Comment: on displaying name from database and storing user point to database

Comment: ok, can you show the php return value? (the format of the json contained in `resp`)

Comment: I didn't understand did u mean file which display the url

Comment: you are making a get request to `usersdb.php` the response of that is stored in `resp` in your ajax call back. what value does it have?

Comment: my userdb.php is a empty file which store email session id and username when he sign up.

Comment: i u have another trick to save points on database please tell me i have no idea of working with session

Comment: ok, maybe you should start with some [basics of ajax with iquery and php](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php)